# Develop Windows 8.0/8.1 app from already existing IBM Worklight Project

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I need to create a Windows Phone 8.0 as well as Windows Phone 8.1 app from already developed IBM Worklight(6.1) Project. Is there any document that elucidates end to end solution to do that? Also could you please elucidate tools/plugins required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your existing MFP/Worklight project, you can add the Windows Phone environment. This will generate the Visual Studio project for Windows Phone. The same app can be run on Windows Phone 8.0 and 8.1.

The following getting started modules give you an overview of whats needed to develop a Windows Phone app.

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/01_07_Setting_up_your_Windows_Phone_8_development_environment.pdf

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_11_General_information_when_developing_for_Windows_Phone_8.pdf

Comment: Hi @Srik, Thank you for the answer. I am facing a problem right now.

I have already developed a hybrid application in which I am calling a RESTful C# web service. The problem is that I need to track those network calls as I am suspecting that my app is unable to reach those RESTful URLs. Kindly suggest how can I do this?

Comment: You can use an application like Wireshark to trace network calls